# Issue with nHibernate upgrade to 3.3

Tags: nhibernate

I just upgraded my .net windows apps from nHibernate 1.2 to 3.3 but having an issue now. During runtime, it throws the following error:

A first chance exception of type 'NHibernate.InvalidProxyTypeException' occurred in NHibernate.dll
NHibernate.InvalidProxyTypeException: The following types may not be used as proxies:
CallType : method Equals should be 'public/protected virtual' or 'protected internal virtual'
.....

Here's the class:

```
public class CallType : DomainObject<int>
{
        public virtual String Description
        {
            get;
            protected set;
        }
        public virtual String Name
        {
            get;
            protected set;
        }

        public CallType()
        {}

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return string.Format("{0}|{1}", Description, Name).GetHashCode();
        }
}
```

Did I miss anything? All members are public virtual. Lazy loading is required in this application

Comment: Should probably keep projects up to date. Updating major versions is bound to break stuff. Incremental changes are easier to fix than jumping like 23243 versions like you have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are inheriting from DomainObject. I suspect this class has a method Equals in it, and it is probably not set to virtual.

The constructor CallType does not need to be virtual as some people mention.

Comment: Yes you are right the DomainObject has the methods are not set to Virtual.